# Jquery click event not working on newly added class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody help me, what i am doing wrong here.

I want to add an class, and when I click on the class, it should remove the class.

```js
$(".processing-signs-direction-cover-sign-direction-selection-process").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected-sign");
});

$(".selected-sign").click(function() {
  $(this).RemoveClass("selected-sign");
  alert(23);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you

Comment: It should be `removeClass` (small `r`).

Comment: Is your div added dynamically?

Comment: Well, it should work... http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnW/7/

Is the class being added on the first click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event is only bound to existing elements. To bind to elements that are dynamically added you can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

But why don't you use [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead?

e.g.

```js
$(".processing-signs-direction-cover-sign-direction-selection-process")
  .click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected-sign");
  });
```

```css
.selected-sign {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="processing-signs-direction-cover-sign-direction-selection-process">click me</div>
```